# Exchange 2010 EVENT ID 1109, msexchange activesync

Tags: exchange-2010, activesync, windows-event-log

the general description is as follows:

> ```
> Some Exchange ActiveSync traffic to the External URL
> ```
>
> https://owa.domain.com/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync
>   is being blocked due to a
>   misconfiguration of the virtual
>   directory
>   WIN2K8EX1\Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync
>   (Default Web Site).  Please make sure
>   that the External URL is stamped
>   correctly using the
>   Set-ActiveSyncVirtualDirectory cmdlet.

whenever i try to run the
get-activesyncvirtualdirectory

> [PS]
>   C:\Windows\system32>get-activesyncvirtualdirectory
>
> An IIS directory entry couldn't be
>   created. The error message is Access
>   is denied.
>
> . HResult = -2147024891
>
> - CategoryInfo          : NotInstalled: (WIN2K8EX1\Micro...fault
>     Web Site):ADObjectId)
>     [Get-ActiveSyncVirtualDirec tory],
>     IISGeneralCOMException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : EEC0CFF1,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.SystemConfigurationTasks.GetMobileSyncVirtualDire
>     ctory
>
> Name:
>
> Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync 
>   (Default...
>
> Server:
>
> WIN2K8EX
>
> InternalUrl:
>
> https://win2k8ex.jewels.local/Micros...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually figured this error out myself.

I installed exchange 2010 on an existing 2007 organization

the problem was, I needed to add the existing 2007 server to the group 'exchange trusted subsystems' and the administrative account (that is used to log onto the exchange 2007 serveR) to the exchange trusted subsystem as well.

This solved all the issues related to the virtual directory that I was experiancing.

also:

I had to add the exchange trusted subsystem into the local administrators group on the exchange 2007 server (..)